# SQL: Average from result set within a radius (Latitude / Longitude)

Tags: sql, coordinates, average, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to get the total average price within a radius by given latitude and longitude.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT avg(price) AS average,
    ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37.3541079) ) * cos( radians( ANY_VALUE(`latitude` )) ) * cos( radians( ANY_VALUE(`longitude`) ) - radians(-121.9552356) ) + sin( radians(37.3541079) ) * sin( radians( ANY_VALUE(`latitude`) ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM `Rental`
HAVING distance <= 20
```

But the result is empty.
The result should looks like this:

> average = 185

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should provide more details like a snapshot of your table. Probably I feel you are missing a group by clause. Things can be much clear if you give some sample data please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `HAVING` in a way that MySQL extends it.  But because you have `AVG()`, it places its normal role as well.

You are going to need a subquery or to move the distance measurement to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT avg(price) as average
FROM (SELECT r.*,
            ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37.3541079) ) * cos( radians( ANY_VALUE(`latitude` )) ) * cos( radians( ANY_VALUE(`longitude`) ) - radians(-121.9552356) ) + sin( radians(37.3541079) ) * sin( radians( ANY_VALUE(`latitude`) ) ) ) ) AS distance 
      FROM `Rental` r
     ) r
WHERE distance <= 20;
```

In other words, calculate the distance.  Then use `WHERE` to filter the rows.  And *then* aggregate for the price.